# Trigger "auto_now" on related model

Tags: django, django-models

I would like the field "updated" to be triggered in the Tag model whenever a M2M relationship is added to a "Tag" in Movie.

I have made an attempt, but the error tells me: `Movie matching query does not exist`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        orig = Movie.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        for t in self.tag.exclude(pk__in=orig.tag.values_list('pk', flat=True)):
            t.save()
        super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also tried using m2m_chagned

```
def movie_changed(sender, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        pass

    m2m_changed.connect(movie_changed, sender=Movie.tags.through)
```

However that also gave me "Movie" not defined.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion- `Task` is irrelevant/a misprint. The traceback: http://dpaste.com/1WQKKM8

Comment: `"Movie" not defined` just means you haven't imported the model in that module.

Comment: Please give me an example of how to user it properly